# celery In a task to calling another task and get the value

Tags: python, celery

```
@app.task(bing=True)
def add1(a,b):

    x = add2.delay(a, b, 2)

    print x.get()

    return x

@app.task()
def add2(a, b, c):
    return a+b+c
```

this way, is error.

```
[2015-07-20 22:54:43,706: WARNING/MainProcess] D:\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\result.py:45: RuntimeWarning: Never call result.get() within a task!
See http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#task-synchronous-subtasks
```

In Celery 3.2 this will result in an exception being
raised instead of just being a warning.

```
warnings.warn(RuntimeWarning(E_WOULDBLOCK))
```

Comment: @app.task(bing=True)
def add1(a,b):
 
 x = add2.delay(a, b, 2)
 # x = add2(a,b)
 print x.get()

 return x

@app.task
def add2(a, b, c):
 return a+b+c